# Match a pipe character in the middle of a string with a python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a pipe character in a string using a Python regex and I can't seem to get it to match. I've boiled it down to a simplified version.

Let's say I am looking for the sequence `z|a` in a string. Here are some possible regexes and the results:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'|', 'xyz|abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2d9a850>
>>> re.match(r'z|', 'xyz|abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2d9a780>
>>> re.match(r'|a', 'xyz|abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2d9a850>
>>> re.match(r'z|a', 'xyz|abc')
>>> re.match(r'z\|a', 'xyz|abc')
>>> re.match(r'z\\|a', 'xyz|abc')
>>> re.match(r'z\\\|a', 'xyz|abc')
>>> re.match(r'z[|]a', 'xyz|abc')
>>>
```

So I can match with `|`, `|a` and `z|` but I can't find a way to match `z|a`. Any ideas?

Comment: Using double quotes instead of single doesn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`re.match()` is looking for a match at the start of the string. Use `re.search()` instead.

The patterns you have that match are matching the empty string. i.e. r'|' is empty string or empty string, r'z|' is z or empty string and '|a' is empty string or a. all of those will match on any string.

```
>>> re.match('z\\|a', 'xyz|abc')
>>> re.search('z\\|a', 'xyz|abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02BF2BB8>
>>> re.search(r'z\|a', 'xyz|abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02BF2BF0>
```

More generally you can use `re.escape()` on a literal string that you need to include in the middle of a more complex regular expression to avoid having to figure out how many backslashes you need to unescape things.

Comment: Ah, thank you - should have realised the match/search issue myself. And bonus points (if I could give them) for `re.escape()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Duncan. Why `'z\\|a'` and `'z\|a'` expressions are returning the same result? After an expression parse, `'z\\|a'` -> `'z\|a'` and `'z\|a'` -> `'z|a'`, hence they should not yield same `search()` result. Please correct me where am going wrong.

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ Both `'z\\|a'` and `'z\|a'` are the exact same strings. In a string `\|` is not a valid Python escape sequence so Python just treats it as two characters.

Comment: Thanks @Duncan, I figured it out. I broke down the steps to: `string parse` (look for escape seq) -> `regex parse`. `z\\|a` evaluates to `z\|a` after string parse and `z\|a` evaluates to `z\|a` as mentioned by you  (`\|` is not a valid escape seq). Since the resultant after `string parse` is same in both cases, the result is too.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following method to get `re.match` to match middle of the string.

```
myPattern = "how"

re.match('(.)*(%s)' %myPattern, 'Hello, how are you ?')*
```

The `.` matches anything in regex. Basically, you are asking for match to skip any number of characters needed to match your pattern.